# What are the controls on the PS3 for Operation Flashpoint : Dragon Rising

Tags: ps3, operation-flashpoint-dragon-rising

I have been playing OF:DR on PS3 and find the movement controls very lacking. I am not sure if this is for realism or if they have not been tuned enough, but one thing remains, they annoy me.

Often I can acquire a target, and am just a little bit to the left or right, and when I try to correct my aim the cross-hair almost always moves too far, this repeats over and over until I can move just the right amount.

Now I am not an FPS n00b, I am a CoD veteran and am (even if I say so myself) pretty good.

Is there some settings which can improve the controls, or am I overreacting?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the controls to be clunky as well with the OF series.  I believe it is done for "realism".

What I will say is that OF is a very different kind of game from CoD (Which I'm sure you've noticed). And the controls are not as easy to manipulate; this **is** done on purpose.

I did have to adjust my controls to keep sane. Unfortunately I'm on PC and don't know about the control settings on PS3.

I would suggest that if you are looking for a more "realism" based game without clunky controls, check out [Project Reality](http://www.realitymod.com/).  It's a free mod for Battlefield 2.

I don't believe I've given you the answer you looked for, and apologize for that.  Just providing my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Very different game than CoD.

Also, CoD (And just about any other FPS) on consoles does have a little bit of aim assist (Ever notice that your aim could have been a little off, and you still managed a headshot). They do this to keep you from going insane (Especially when you are used to Keyboard and Mouse). CoD is made for everyone who can grasp the 'two thumbstick shooter' principle. Accessibillity is one of their main concerns.

Now for OPF:DR:
Because of the often far distance of enemies when you engage, codemasters decided that Aim Assist didn't work (They tried, but it had difficulty choosing a target when they where 3/4 pixels apart...). This also makes the game a lot harder, mostly on purpose. Just keep low (Crouching and crawling also make your aim more accurate) and take your time to make a shot. Make em count!

This game is hard and frustrating... But if you are into that kind of thing (COD doesn't do anything for me personally) is a very rewarding experience.